# Управление окнами Tkinter. Вставить график Matplotlib в окно Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, matplotlib

Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста, с решением такой задачи. В *Tkinter* создаю окно и кнопки. Одна из кнопок запускает функцию, которая выводит окно графика *Matplotlib*.

- Вопрос 1: как с помощью кнопки в окне *Tkinter* закрыть окно *Matplotlib*
- Вопрос 2: можно ли вывести график *Matplotlib* в окно *Tkinter*? И если
  да, то как?

```
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random import choice

x_list = [0]

y_list = [0]

def fill_arrs():

    counter = 10000

    while counter > 0:
        x_direction = choice([1, -1])
        x_dist = choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        x_step = x_direction * x_dist
        x = x_list[-1] + x_step
        x_list.append(x)

        y_direction = choice([1, -1])
        y_dist = choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        y_step = y_direction * y_dist
        y = y_list[-1] + y_step
        y_list.append(y)

        counter -= 1


def generate_scatter_chart():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax =fig.add_subplot(111)

    fill_arrs()

    ax.scatter(x_list, y_list, s = 1)

    plt.show()

def close_scatter_chart():
    pass



window = Tk()
window.config(pady = 20, padx = 20)

btn = Button(text = 'Generate scatter chart', command = generate_scatter_chart, padx = 5, pady = 5)
btn.pack()

btn2 = Button(text = 'Close scatter chart', command = close_scatter_chart, padx = 5, pady = 5)
btn2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from random import choice


x_list = [0]
y_list = [0]

def fill_arrs():
    counter = 10000
    while counter > 0:
        x_direction = choice([1, -1])
        x_dist = choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        x_step = x_direction * x_dist
        x = x_list[-1] + x_step
        x_list.append(x)

        y_direction = choice([1, -1])
        y_dist = choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        y_step = y_direction * y_dist
        y = y_list[-1] + y_step
        y_list.append(y)

        counter -= 1

def generate_scatter_chart(uebergebene_daten=(10, 10, 10, 10)):
    global canvas1
    if canvas1:
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().destroy()
    datenplot = uebergebene_daten
    fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 4), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

    fill_arrs()   
    ax.scatter(x_list, y_list, s = 1)    

    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
    canvas1.draw()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=NONE, expand=0)
    window.after(200, None)

def close_scatter_chart():
    global canvas1
    if canvas1:
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().destroy()    
    

window = Tk() 

canvas1 = None

window.title('Plotting in Tkinter') 
window.geometry("700x500") 

btn = Button(
    master = window, 
    text = 'Generate scatter chart', 
    command = generate_scatter_chart, 
    padx = 5, pady = 5
)
btn.pack()

btn2 = Button(
    master = window, 
    text = 'Close scatter chart', 
    command = close_scatter_chart, 
    padx = 5, pady = 5
)
btn2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PaulManik что не так?